# SQL Server Express - Commercial use

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm developing a web site and i would like to use the SQL Server Express as my DB.
The Express edition is limited for 4GB per DB.

Is it legal to create & use several DB's for the use of a single web site?

Comment: Is it worth the effort of doing this? If you don't want to pay, why not consider some of the free alternatives like PostGreSQL?

Answer (score 5):

What about trying to migrate [SQL Server Express 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/) who allow 10GB per DB ?

Comment: Which is exactly the same as SQL Express 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not, based on Microsoft's feature and limitations page: [SQL Server Editions](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions.aspx)

The hard limitations, per that link, of the Express Edition, are:

> SQL Server Express supports 1 physical
>   processor, 1 GB memory, and 10 GB
>   storage

Comment: thanks, but just to be clear i meant the use of full 4GB on each DB.

Comment: meaning that i'll have 16 GB total for 4 DB's on a single site.

Comment: The limitation is 10GB, not 4GB, as you will see if you read the link that Michael Goldshteyn posted.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the licence agreement and satisfy yourself about how the product can be used. Note that the actual limit in SQL Server Express 2008 R2 is **10GB**, not 4GB.

However, you should seriously consider whether Express is the right choice for this application. Splitting the data into four databases will still leave you restricted to only 1GB RAM. That's a significant scalability limitation for web site usage.